# Large background-image VS small repeated background-image

Tags: html, css, performance, background-image

I'm using a texture, concretely [linen texture](http://turbo.premiumpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/preview11.jpg), I have not been able to make this with CSS gradients. So, my question is about performance:

Which is best, a large background-image or a small background-image which is repeated?

Comment: What do you consider *performance*? Time loading the page for the client, load of the server, data downloaded and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of my comment, downloading a small image and tiling it is much cheaper than having a big image. If you use a tiled image, you get the following advantages:

- Lower **bandwidth used** on the server.
- Shorter **download time** from the browser.
- About **rendering time** I'm not sure, you must run some benchmarks here but it'ss probably negligible.

So you normally would want to have a tiled image. *However*, you want to make sure that your image has a flat enough texture to make the tiling of it not perceived as a strong repeating pattern. Your image seems good enough though.

As an alternative, you can have both to have short loading time and high quality:

[The Layered Look: Better Responsive Images Using Multiple Backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/the-layered-look/)

Answer (score 3):

> "Which is best, a large background-image or a small background-image which is repeated?"

The latter. Repetition has little or no impact on performance whereas file-size most certainly does